# Controls inside a box with background color in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

In my form, i have some text boxes to get inputs from the user. And i calculated some values depends on e the input. I display all calculated values in the same form in right side.
I have many number of forms for different logics. Each form have 10 inputs and more number of outputs. SO to get a look, i thought place all input controls inside box with some green background and output controls in Blue box. 
For this i used Group box from toolbox and i deleted the 'Text' value from properties.
But when i fill background color,the color get filled above the box line.
How can i avoid that? Is there any other option to do that?
[image: Form Screenshot]

Comment: This is how the `GroupBox` behaves. You could draw the color yourself if you know where its lines are located. -- On the other hand a workaround would be to place a panel inside it and change its back color instead.

Answer (score 2):

Within VB there is a tool called a `panel` , maybe this is what you would like to look at? The panel allows you to group things and when you change the colour, there is no line so you will not notice the overfill.